# Why do I get a linking error with clang when inlining a function in a C program?

Tags: c, clang, inline

Why doesn't the following program compile with clang?

```
#include <stdio.h>

inline int f() {
  return 42;
}

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", f());
}
```

I get the following:

```
$ clang -o inline inline.c
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_f", referenced from:
      _main in inline-975155.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

But I can compile it with clang++ just fine. Is there some nuance between `inline` in C vs C++?

Comment: There are definitely differences between C and C++ for inline functions.  I'm not sure which difference you're running into, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Very simple: Inlining does not work if you do not enable optimizations.

[image]

https://godbolt.org/z/KrWq4PGhd

To sort this problem out you need to instruct the compiler to emit not inline version as well:

```
extern inline int f() {
  return 42;
}
```

Then it will work in both cases (will be inlined or not)

[image]
https://godbolt.org/z/dh3G18PqK

CLANG works exactly the same way:

https://godbolt.org/z/ssMnzf5MG

https://godbolt.org/z/ssMnzf5MG

Comment: I didn't DV, but probably for using images.

Comment: It wasn't me either.

Comment: I didn't know about using `extern inline` though. That's interesting!

Comment: You have images and links for everything. There is no other way of showing it. There is no **code** in the images

Answer (score 1):

In C99 you need to provide an alternate (non-inline) definition of the function for when the compiler can't inline. See https://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#inline

One of the solutions may work for you, is to make the definition static:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

static inline int f() {
  return 42;
}

int main() {
  printf("%d\n", f());
}
```

will work as you expect.

Here are all the options listed in the on the linked `clang` page:

> - Change add to a static inline function. This is usually the right solution if only one translation unit needs to use the function. static inline functions are always resolved within the translation unit, so you won't have to add a non-inline definition of the function elsewhere in your program.
> - Remove the inline keyword from this definition of `f`. The inline keyword is not required for a function to be inlined, nor does it guarantee that it will be. Some compilers ignore it completely. Clang treats it as a mild suggestion from the programmer.
> - Provide an external (non-inline) definition of `f` somewhere else in your program. The two definitions must be equivalent!
> - Compile in the GNU C89 dialect by adding -std=gnu89 to the set of Clang options. This option is only recommended if the program source cannot be changed or if the program also relies on additional C89-specific behavior that cannot be changed.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me until I read the web site. It sounds like they have to write a second definition.

Comment: Well they do if they want to use if outside that translation unit as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

In 6.7.4 7, the C 2018 standard says an inline definition does not provide an external definition:

> … An inline definition does not provide an external definition for the function…

and that a compiler may use an inline definition or an external definition:

> … It is unspecified whether a call to the function uses the inline definition or the external definition.

Thus, a compiler may compile a call to `f` as a call to the inline definition, which will not result in a link error, or as a call to an external definition, which will result in a link error if you have not provided an external definition. The compiler’s choice may be affected by optimization switches and other settings.

The C++ standard does not have this wording (but I will leave it to others to provide additional interpretation of the C++ standard).